# How set class in include html file using jsp

Tags: html, jsp

I have included header.html in index.jsp using

```
<%@ include file="include_files/header.html" %>
```

Now I want to include same header on multiple pages but the active tab should be set to different tab each time.

Please suggest.

The Header.html has this ul.

```
<header id="header" class="fixed-top">
  <div class="container d-flex align-items-center">
    <h1 class="logo mr-auto"><a href="index.html">Euc Stories</a></h1>
    <!-- Uncomment below if you prefer to use an image logo -->
    <!-- <a href="index.html" class="logo mr-auto"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="" class="img-fluid"></a>-->
    <nav class="nav-menu d-none d-lg-block">
      <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="courses.html">Courses</a></li>
        <li><a href="trainers.html">Trainers</a></li>
        <li><a href="events.html">Events</a></li>
        <li><a href="pricing.html">Pricing</a></li>
        <li class="drop-down"><a href="">Drop Down</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Drop Down 1</a></li>
            <li class="drop-down"><a href="#">Deep Drop Down</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Deep Drop Down 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Deep Drop Down 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Deep Drop Down 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Deep Drop Down 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Deep Drop Down 5</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Drop Down 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Drop Down 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Drop Down 4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <!-- .nav-menu -->
    <a href="courses.html" class="get-started-btn">Get Started</a> </div>
</header>
```

Comment: You need to add logic i.e to active which tab at server-side using jsp code .

Comment: Can you please share any reference code for that and also one more point, the tab names and the page names are same

Comment: This is also one solution which you have posted as answer .But , it would be more easier if you print your `lis` using for-loop then you don't  need to check `if()..` individually for every li . There you would directly use only one `if..` to check that condition.

Answer (score 0):

Send page name to each url ie index.html?page_name=home

Then call the page name variable from within your page

```
$page_name = $_GET['page_name'];
```

You could use a switch statement to set the active link

```
switch ($page_name){ 
        case 'home':
            $active ='active';
            break;
                
        case 'about':
            $active1 ='active';
            break;
                
        case 'courses':
            $active2 ='active';
            break;
        
        case 'trainers':
            $active3 ='active';
            break;
                
        default:
    // Set a default
}
```

Then set your links up to activate if the condition from the switch statement is true.

```
<li><a class="<?= $active; ?> nav-btn" href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a class="<?= $active1; ?> nav-btn" href="#">about</a></li>
<li><a class="<?= $active2; ?> nav-btn" href="#">courses</a></li>
<li><a class="<?= $active3; ?> nav-btn" href="#">Teachers</a></li>
```

You will need to set a default. Maybe an if statement. if(!isset($page_name)){ $page_name="home"; }

Comment: Hi  question is asked for  `jsp` not `php` .

Answer (score 0):

I tried below one after each list.
Please suggest if any different more feasible approach.

**header.jsp**:

```
    <%
String uri = request.getRequestURI();
String page_name = uri.substring(uri.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
System.out.println("Page Name: "+page_name);
%>

<header id="header" class="fixed-top">
  <div class="container d-flex align-items-center">
    <h1 class="logo mr-auto"><a href="index.jsp">Euc Stories</a></h1>
    <!-- Uncomment below if you prefer to use an image logo -->
    <!-- <a href="index.html" class="logo mr-auto"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="" class="img-fluid"></a>-->
    <nav class="nav-menu d-none d-lg-block">
      <ul>
        <li <% if("index.jsp".equals(page_name) || page_name.length()==0) out.print("class=\"active\""); %>><a href="index.jsp">Home</a></li>
        <li <% if("about.jsp".equals(page_name)) out.print("class=\"active\""); %>><a href="about.jsp">About</a></li>
        <li <% if("courses.jsp".equals(page_name)) out.print("class=\"active\""); %>><a href="courses.jsp">Courses</a></li>
        <li <% if("trainers.jsp".equals(page_name)) out.print("class=\"active\""); %>><a href="trainers.jsp">Trainers</a></li>
        <li <% if("events.jsp".equals(page_name)) out.print("class=\"active\""); %>><a href="events.jsp">Events</a></li>
        <li <% if("pricing.jsp".equals(page_name)) out.print("class=\"active\""); %>><a href="pricing.jsp">Pricing</a></li>
        <li class="drop-down"><a href="">Drop Down</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Drop Down 1</a></li>
            <li class="drop-down"><a href="#">Deep Drop Down</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Deep Drop Down 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Deep Drop Down 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Deep Drop Down 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Deep Drop Down 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Deep Drop Down 5</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Drop Down 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Drop Down 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Drop Down 4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li <% if("contact.jsp".equals(page_name)) out.print("class=\"active\""); %>><a href="contact.jsp">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <!-- .nav-menu -->
    <a href="courses.jsp" class="get-started-btn">Get Started</a> </div>

</header>
```